# problem with newcommand with line break \\ and tabular inside

Tags: tables, macros, line-breaking

I define a new command `\nonBranchingRule` that takes 3 arguments.
Intuitively, it defines a rule where the last argument is a comment (optional argument) for the rule.
I want to place the comment under the rule and center both.
I do it with tabular. 
I add tabular lines to test the real arrangement of a rule and a comment.

MWE below:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}


\newcommand{\nonBranchingRule}[3][]{
\begin{tabular}{|c|}
$\dfrac{
    \begin{tabular}{c}
            #2
    \end{tabular}}
{
    \raisebox{-4pt}{
        \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
            #3
    \end{tabular}}
}$#1
\end{tabular}}


\begin{document}

\nonBranchingRule{$H$}
{$G$}
{\\$G$ and $H$ are terms}

\vspace{2cm}

\begin{tabular}{|c|}
$\dfrac{  
    \begin{tabular}{c}
            $H$
    \end{tabular}
}
{
    \raisebox{-4pt}{
        \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
            $G$
        \end{tabular}}
}$\\$G$ and $H$ are terms
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

I would like to get the second case but with `\nonBranchingRule`  I am getting the first one.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You had the `#1` `#2` #3` in the wrong order, and an unused optional argument.

Here I show two forms `\nonBranchingRule` with three mandatory arguments and
`\nonBranchingRuleB` where the rule argument is optional argument given first, in `[]`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}


\newcommand{\nonBranchingRule}[3]{
\begin{tabular}{|c|}
$\dfrac{
    \begin{tabular}{c}
            #1
    \end{tabular}}
{
    \raisebox{-4pt}{
        \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
            #2
    \end{tabular}}
}$#3
\end{tabular}}


\newcommand{\nonBranchingRuleB}[3][]{
\begin{tabular}{|c|}
$\dfrac{
    \begin{tabular}{c}
            #2
    \end{tabular}}
{
    \raisebox{-4pt}{
        \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
            #3
    \end{tabular}}
}$#1
\end{tabular}}


\begin{document}

\nonBranchingRule{$H$}
{$G$}
{\\$G$ and $H$ are terms}

\vspace{2cm}

\nonBranchingRuleB
{$H$}
{$G$}

\vspace{2cm}

\nonBranchingRuleB
[\\$G$ and $H$ are terms]
{$H$}
{$G$}


\vspace{2cm}

\begin{tabular}{|c|}
$\dfrac{  
    \begin{tabular}{c}
            $H$
    \end{tabular}
}
{
    \raisebox{-4pt}{
        \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
            $G$
        \end{tabular}}
}$\\$G$ and $H$ are terms
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry I added that the comment is optional.
That is why order was different.
So, in your solution how to accommodate a comment as optional?

Comment: @FiboKowalsky `\newcommand` can only make `#1` optional, and the syntax would be `\zzz[optional comment]{top}{bottom}` with the optional argument in `[]` not `{}`

Comment: @FiboKowalsky answer updated showing optional argument form